# Who have to validate STS security token lifetime

Tags: validation, token, wif, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

We have a custom active STS based on WIF. It normally issues standard security tokens by client requests. In the STS Service configuration we has been set DefaultTokenLifetime parameter to 1 min.

After that we are calling our server with applied token every 15 sec. But after 1 minute has elapsed, our calls to the server finish successfully. This is strange behavior!
Who has to validate the ValidTo parameter of the security token?

What is the best practice to validate security token in RP (business logic service)?

**UPD:**
It seems we found workaround.
By the way we are using follow code on client side:

```
ChannelFactory<ICalculator> calcFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>( GetClientBinding(), ServiceAddress );
calcFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory();
ICalculator calc = calcFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
                for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
                {
                    double sum = calc.Add(40.0, 2.0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Called. Token ValidTo: {0} but now: {1}", token.ValidTo.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
```

This code create channel factory one time and use it per call. *If we will create channel factory on each call, the security token will be validated correctly*: when token has expired service call will not be authenticated and a security exception will be thrown. Its work but is it good practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, WIF uses a clock skew of 5 mins to accommodate machines clocks. This could explain why your token is still accepted after the 1 min expiration.

Comment: Allen, our client, server and sts running on local computer. But I've tried to set ServiceConfiguration.MaxClockSkew to 1 seconds - no results

Comment: Similar question found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65ede7e8-98ea-46f8-8826-76534f4af5ac/security-token-lifetime?forum=Geneva